# I can't boot from USB after installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

On my old laptop (Acer Aspire ES1-311), I tried installing Ubuntu 17.10 (when it was the latest version) several times and failed, it would just not boot unless I got the live USB and used it there. So I sent my laptop for repair and they installed 16.04. Now I have updated to 18.04 and kernel 5.0.0 but this problem was there even on 16.04, but not before it (back when I still had Windows):
BIOS won't detect any USB flash drive. I tried with at least 5 different flash drives, 16GB, 8GB, 4GB and it just wouldn't detect it, like, even in Legacy boot mode, in the boot order, it won't list the USB models, just "USB CD/DVD:" "USB Floppy:" and one more thing which I forgot, even when I tried Rufus, Unetbootin, SUSE Studio Imagewriter and at least like 3 others and it was done properly. I looked at so many tutorials, no, that laptop doesn't have a disk drive, anything I've tried just wouldn't work. So, how can I install a different OS from a bootable USB if it won't detect it in the BIOS/What can I do to make my BIOS detect the USB? Thanks.

Comment: I'm a little confused, and perhaps you can set me straight.  You are currently on 18.04 with kernel 5.0.0?  So at some point, you did boot from a USB to do the installations?  And now the computer will not boot unless the USB is installed, but the BIOS will not recognize a USB anymore?

Comment: No, it boots perfectly fine with 18.04, that live USB thingy was before I had even installed ubuntu. And yes, the BIOS will not recognize a USB anymore. Yes at some point I did boot from USB, but now I can't.

Comment: I have an odd situation on my CPU, where sometimes a bootable USB is not recognize unless I do a cold boot.  Could you try that?

Comment: I have tried that, cold boot doesn't work either unfortunately.